# Firefox 38.0.1 is continue showing browser loading symbol even if my pdf file is opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, pdf

As a requirement we need to support the firefox version 38.0.1 for pdf file display their is an issue with the pdf file opening when it is opened in the browser the loading symbol is still showing any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

```
                $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
                var randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                var pdfWindow = window.open(fileURL, "PDF View" + randomnumber);
                var pdfHtmlData = '<body><head><title>PDF View</title></head><iframe src="'+fileURL+'"  width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">' + $scope.content + '</iframe></body>';
                pdfWindow.document.write(pdfHtmlData);
```

I have used the iframe let me know if it's the correct way to view the pdf file.

Comment: Do you have to support other browsers? Does it work in them?

Comment: Yes it is supporting the other browsers.